# Nginx and relative paths for proxied subdomain

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I'm a newbie in Nginx, trying to learn.

I have the server under `mydomain.com` and my static site under `my-app.mydomain.com`
All the paths are relative, so `images/image.png` resolves to `my-app.mydomain.com/images/image.png`.

I also have a second app, `new-app.mydomain.com` which has the same issue, the relative paths are trying to be resolved to `mydomain.com`

I don't know how to fix this and I would like to avoid having to make all paths absolute. Also, I would like a solution that allows me to keep adding new `locations` blocks for the new app and load the resources. I want to avoid some restrictive that could work for the main app but not for the other.

```
    location /new-app {
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass "mydomain.com";
    }
```

I will appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

Locations inside a server can help you configure website/content that need to be displayed on sub-routes of website. Sub-domains need to be configured in a seperate nginx file similar to main domain in which you can add as many location as per your requirement.

Nginx files:-

1. `mydomain.com`

```
server{
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass "mydomain.com"; # This should be server with port on which your server is running on VM(virtual machine)
        root /var/www/html/mydomain.com; #In case you want to server static files
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

2. `new-app.mydomain.com`

```
server{
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name new-app.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass "new-app.mydomain.com"; # This should be server with port on which your server is running on VM(virtual machine)
        root /var/www/html/new-app.mydomain.com; #In case you want to server static files
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```